# How to create a diagonal line in responsive background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a diagonal background in the background of an element. I can do this quite easily using a gradient, however this for a responsive website so the element needs to be fluid.

I can do something like this for a fixed shape...

```
div {
  width:200p
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:2em;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,#ffffff 49%,#aaa 50%,#ffffff 51%);
}
```

This is using a rotated gradient with a hard stop, but it is using a fixed width. I have done a codepen here of how it would look with a width set in percentages, and as you can see, the concept breaks. http://codepen.io/juicypixels/pen/gPravL?editors=110

Would be very interested to see if there is a responsive way of doing this, even if I have to use javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `to side` syntax instead of angles.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
background:linear-gradient(to bottom left,#ffffff 49%,#aaa 50%,#ffffff 51%);
```

instead of

```
background:linear-gradient(45deg,#ffffff 49%,#aaa 50%,#ffffff 51%);
```